# How to force terminate a Python 3 program in Windows?

Tags: python, windows

I am running Python 3 code in a windows Command line prompt. 
The program has an infinite loop that I use. (While (1))
Sounds like bad design but it's meant to be like this.

Is there a way to force close the program without having to close the command prompt. 
In the terminal, Ctrl + C often works for this.

Comment: Have you tried to `break` out of the loop?

Comment: I want to break out using a keyboard shortcut/interrupt.  Normally Ctrl-C works just fine. Esp with Terminal

Comment: Assuming your loop involves user input, you can do this by simply having the user enter a certain string, like "q" or "quit," and pressing Enter. If it's a long calculation that you want the user to be able to interrupt, any method you use will be blocked, so you'd have to either kill it with Ctrl+C or Task Manager or use multiple threads/processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sys.exit(exit_code)` or `raise SystemExit(string_to_print_before_exiting)`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit

https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit

Comment: Since the issue is an infinite loop, `break` would have the same effect as `sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ctrl-C generates KeyboardInterrupt Exception, so unless you blindly catch all exceptions and ignore them, it should do just that. (If you do catch all, can add an exception for KeyboardInterrupt). Interestingly, this does not work for me because I am using Cygwin.
2. You can force-terminate the program using task manager. However, if you have more than one python process running, this can be tricky. To do this, have your process print PID in the first lines of the log file (you do have a log file, right?)

`print("started process", os.getpid())`

- To see process: tasklist /FI "PID eq 1234"
- To kill process: taskkill /PID 1234 /F

---

3. Advanced process interruption:
   Have your program wait for command on a socket.

Comment: my program had two threads, first is infinite loop and second is for sqlite. Because sqlite thread never exited somehow on ctrl+C or SIGTERM, i added the following to the end of the program: `os.system(f'kill -s SIGKILL {os.getpid()}')`. works like a charm

Comment: You can also use: taskkill /F /IM PYTHON.EXE